# Can a vector class in C++ be used like a Dictionary class in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, vector, hashtable

Can a vector class in C++ be used like a Dictionary class in C#?  You basically can have a vector class store classes of the same type.  A member of that class can be regarded as a Key and the remaining members can be thought of as data.

Comment: Why use a vector when you could use a map/unordered_map?

Comment: You can, but it won't offer the benefits of a dictionary like constant lookup time.

Comment: You can use `std::find_if` on a vector if that's what you want, but there's very little point in doing it since `std::map` exists.

Comment: @chris: `unordered_map` does, but `vector` does not. So it's a weird question.

Comment: @MSalters, I was referring to using `std::vector` in place of a C# `Dictionary`. `std::vector` doesn't offer constant lookup time and `Dictionary` does. I would definitely recommend using a proper swap like `unordered_map`.

Comment: In C# the instances are references and the reference is hashable (for dictionary).  In C++ if you're mapping pointer X -> instance, the instance may be moved by the map, so this will be dangerous (the key will no longer point to the actual memory location of the object).  You could hash a pointer to an instance to pointers to instances, in which case you'd be ok.

Comment: @Robinson: "The instance may be moved" -- no

Comment: In C# Dictionary<Object, Object> is effectively std::unordered_map<Object *, Object *>.

Answer (score 0):

No, the vector class in general won't stay sorted when you add members. That means you can't efficiently find items in it, you need a linear scan.

Use `std::unordered_map` for a key-value container which does offer O(1) key lookup.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to make a dictionary in C++ is to use a map or unordered_map.  Since a map is an associative container it has a key, value pair.  The key is used for the look-up and the value is the data associated to it.  So in this case the key would be the word and the value would be the definition.

I would suggest that you use an unordered_map since the look-up speed is on average constant time and at worst it is O(N)